# Is there a command line tool for AutoSys R4 JobProfiles?

Tags: autosys

AutoSys R4 has a variety of command line tools.  Example: `jil` (UNIX) and `jil.exe` (Win32) let you insert/update/delete box and job definitions using a script.

Is there an equivalent command line tool for `jobprofiles.exe`?  I searched hard on Google and found nothing.  Oddly, all the FAQs I see avoid any discussion of job profiles.  Why is this?

Currently, there is no way (as a regular user) to dump an entire jobprofile.  This would be useful for many reasons, including comparison to other jobprofiles, e.g., PROD vs UAT.

FYI: AutoSys R4 job profiles allow you to set certain environment variables when your process runs.  Example: `MY_CONFIG_VAR=1234`